# postgresql-10 : The program "initdb" is needed by pg_ctl but was not found in the same directory as "pg_ctl" Check your Installation

Tags: centos7, postgresql-10

I am new to this forum,  i am facing this issue, where i get the below error.

```
sudo -u shahid ./pg_ctl -D /root/pgsql10x/data/ initdb
invalid binary "/root/pgsql10x/bin/pg_ctl"
invalid binary "/root/pgsql10x/bin/pg_ctl"
invalid binary "/root/pgsql10x/bin/pg_ctl"

The program "initdb" is needed by pg_ctl but was not found in the same directory as "pg_ctl".

Check your installation.
```

I am trying to run this from root.

I have built from the source. I am trying version 10. on CentOS7.
I downloaded direct from postgres site.

I am not facing this problem when I run as non-root user.

I have all the files in the bin directory, as shared in image here:

[image: bin directory files]

Comment: If you run this as root, then why do you use `sudo`?

Comment: "*I have built from the source.*" ... why?

Comment: "*the bin directory*" - which `bin` directory? Also, post text as text, not pictures of text.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - > Postgres cannot be started as a root user. that's a limitation.

Comment: @melpomene - Because, i need it to run on both centOS & RHEL on 2 different versions 6 & 7.

Comment: @melpomene The bin directory is of postgres, which i am worried about. The image does the justice here, as the copy paste of output is not legible to read.

Comment: @melpomene- The idea to down vote is agreed for java/C/Pyhon type of code. When i am giving you all the details here, and explaining the scenario, your idea of downvote is just adding more pain to existing problem. What more can you investigate in the 'ls' command where every details is  already listed and captured here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I was able to resolve the issue.

The problem was due to the built source was directly placed in "/root/" directory as 
/root/pgsql10x/ in root login.

when i placed it in "/app/" directory as /app/pgsql10x/ things started working normally, database got created and database got working without any problem (in root login).

-Shahid

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from the fact that you are trying to start the cluster as the `root` user you'll have to switch to `postgres` and try restarting the cluster again

```
su - postgres
pg_ctl start
```